# Ruby string containing ${...}

Tags: ruby

In the Ruby string :

```
"${0} ${1} ${2:hello}"
```

is `${i}` the ith argument in the command that called this particular file.

Tried searching the web for "Ruby ${0}" however the search engines don't like non-alphanumeric characters.

Consulted a Ruby book which says #{...} will substitute the results of the code in the braces, however this does not mention ${...}, is this a special syntax to substitute argvalues into a string, thanks very much,

Joel

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly are you asking about, but that does not seem to be the behaviour of ruby strings.

Comment: $0 is the script file, but args are in ARGV. $n where n>1 are special match vars. Looks more like bash or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned above `${0}` will do nothing special, `$0` gives the name of the script, `$1` gives the first match from a regular expression.

To interpolate a command line argument you'd normally do this:

```
puts "first argument = #{ARGV[0]}"
```

However, ARGV is also aliased as `$*` so you could also write

```
puts "first argument = #{$*[0]}"
```

Perhaps that's where the confusion arose?